# Continuous Measurement of Cassandra Insertion speed

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I have an application that writes into a Cassandra cluster in a distributed fashion. Different threads may write to different cassandra nodes, and writing threads may be launched form different hosts.

Is there a way for me to measure the cumulative insertion speed? That is I want to know the total number of records being inserted at any given time.

I'm using hector with Cassandra 0.8.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra exposes a ton of performance metrics over JMX.  A good place to start is http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/operations/monitoring.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however none of that information is helpful in determining the cumulative insertion speed. For instance, Cassandra does export "WriteCount", however there is no way to know in how much time those writes occurred.

Comment: Surely you can record the time at which you asked for the writecount.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of that :)